# Django Timezone filter returns wrong results

Tags: python, django

I wrote the following code:

```
date = self.request.query_params.get('date')       
queryset = Fixture.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        
if(date):
    date = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")).astimezone(pytz.UTC)
    queryset = Fixture.objects.filter(date__date=date).order_by('date')
```

Upon excuting this with `date = "2020-09-02"` the queryset returns values containing the date "2020-09-03". How come this happens and how can this be solved?

Comment: What is the value of `TIME_ZONE` settings variable?

Comment: It is set to 'True'

Comment: What...? `USE_TZ` and `TIME_ZONE` are different settings variables. Can you double-check the values?

Comment: The value is UTC

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with a date, why make it a datetime first? Your parsing could be simplified.

```
date = self.request.query_params.get('date')       
queryset = Fixture.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        
if date:
    date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    queryset = Fixture.objects.filter(date__date=date).order_by('date')
```

But this parsing is also is sensitive for wrongly inserted data, and you'll get an error. Best practice imo would be creating a simple form with a DateField.

```
class ParseDateForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField()

# This somewhere in a method
form = ParseDateForm(data=self.request.query_params)
queryset = Fixture.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        
if form.is_valid():
    date = form.cleaned_data['date']
    queryset = Fixture.objects.filter(date__date=date).order_by('date')
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question and does not answer it. Implementing this would still return me fixtures with the wrong date

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain what your problem was. The first problem, which my answer shows, is you parse your date to a (utc) datetime, not a date. The other problem is that  your Fixtures model contain timezoned datetimes (I guess, as you have not gave us your model). Thus with __date the datetimes are converted to a date. This could possibly not the local date. As the datetime in a mysql db is utc, postgres is timezone aware.